# how to calculate the coordinate points for the fitBounds()?

Tags: mapbox, fitbounds

How do I calculate the coordinate points for the fitBounds() method to get the exact area in MapBox?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve precisely? Are you looking for a way to call `fitBounds()` on a Line/Polygon/Array of polygons?

Comment: I want to achieve this --> https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/  In this example they are getting Kenya in view I want city Stockholm. I do not understand how they calculated Coordinates e.g [
        32.958984,
        -5.353521
    ], [
        43.50585,
        5.615985
    ] . when I am passing coordinates for stockhokm its giving me warning "Map cannot fit within canvas with the given bounds, padding, and/or offset."

Answer (score 0):

To convert your coordinates to a bounding box you can use [`turf.bbox`](http://turfjs.org/docs#bbox):

```
var featureBbox = turf.bbox(feature);
```